# Error in setting foreign key for table using Django

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-models, foreign-keys

I was trying to set foreignkey of one column of one table but encountered a problem.
I defined four classes as follow:

```
class Genes(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
notes = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'Genes'


class Metabolites(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
compartment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
charge = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
formula = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
notes = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'Metabolites'


class Reactions(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
metabolites = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
lower_bound = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
upper_bound = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
gene_reaction_rule = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
subsystem = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
notes = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'Reactions'


class Reactionsmeta(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
metabolite1 = models.ForeignKey(Metabolites, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
stoichiometry1 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
metabolite2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
stoichiometry2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
#...
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'ReactionsMeta'
```

And as for the Reactionsmeta class, the data of metabolite1, metabilite2,...are the id of each metabolites. So, I want to set the metabolite1,2,3....as the foreignkey which point to the class Metabolites. However, when I did that, the error occurred which tells me:

(1054, "Unknown column 'ReactionsMeta.metabolite1_id' in 'field list'")

Could someone please tell me where I did wrong?

Comment: Post full traceback please. Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: All your tables are unmanaged, so Django doesn't create them. Are you sure the Metabolites table has an ID field in the database?

Comment: Yes, I did run makemigrations and migrate

Comment: Actually, I used inspectdb function to generate the model, so yes, the metabolite table does has an ID field

Comment: Inspectdb doesn't output ForeignKeys, so you've modified this yourself. Please show the underlying schema.

Comment: Yes, I manually set the typefield of 'metabolite1' as a foreign key, but then the error occurred.....and what do you mean by 'underlying schema?'